# Wordpress - manually relate a post to page(s)?

Tags: plugin-development

So, either I'm searching for a plugin or I'll try to develop one for this purpose but I can't seem to find anything applicable. Perhaps I wasn't searching with the correct terms.

What I have setup is something like this: there are 3 types of posts/pages that I want to relate to one another. Lets say I have a baseball player as a post. That player has an agent and a team they play for. When I go to their edit-post area in the Wordpress admin I want to be able to have a drop-down list that allows the admin to choose who their agent is from a pool of all agent's in the system. A similar drop down would let you designate what team they play for from a pool of all teams in the system.

In addition to this, each team and each agent would have the same functionality. As an admin, you would be able to inter-relate each type of post (player/team/agent) using a similar method.

Basically, it would look in the database for all of the posts with the category "player", "team" and "agent", then let you link them together, either once or multiple instances for a post so that when you go to the players page, you can find out their agent's info and their team info, all with the ability to go to the agent's post or team post as well.

Any idea if something exists or what I may be looking for?

Answer (score 2):

#### Unfortunately Post or object relationships is not possible in WordPress without doing a lot of extra work.

This feature is being actively discussed on this **[trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14513)** any additional support for this would help our case of getting this included in core.

Your only options are:

1. Use a plugin and modify it to fit your use case

   - http://www.zigpress.com/wordpress/plugins/zigconnect/
   - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/
2. Map your posts to specially crafted taxonomies. (slow)
3. Store relationships in postmeta. (very slow if you ever need to use that in a join statement)
4. Create your own post2post table.

Further Reading:

- [Linking Two Post Types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16292/linking-two-post-types)
- [How to insert content from another Custom Post type into Post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8078/how-to-insert-content-from-another-custom-post-type-into-post)
- [Is It Possible To Have Shared Wordpress Custom Post Types?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6404/is-it-possible-to-have-shared-wordpress-custom-post-types)
- [[Plugin: Posts 2 Posts] How does it work?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15456/how-does-scribus-posts-2-posts-work)
- [How Do I Use The Wordpress Plugin Posts 2 Posts by Scribu?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11899/how-do-i-use-the-wordpress-plugin-posts-2-posts-by-scribu)

Comment: Thanks - that helps. I ended up finding a plugin that seems to do similar to what I need. Just gotta modify and test it out. http://www.microkid.net/wordpress/related-posts